# How can I access a webapp on WildFly 12 server from another computer?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-12

Hello I have a webapp on Wild Fly 12 server and I want a colleague from work to access it. When I try to access it with my ip (from my computer or his) it says it can not connect). It only works from my computer with localhost. This is what I`ve tried:

I replaced in standalone.xml the old  tags with this:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">

        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>

    </interface>

    <interface name="public">

        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/> 

    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

But it doesn`t work...Do you have any solutions ? Thank you

Comment: Any firewall software on your computer that may be blocking traffic?

Comment: The computer is in a network with proxy

Comment: that is not an answer to my question.

Comment: I checked the firewall on my computer and it is turned off

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy to analyze with the given information. Your configuration is correct, it should work.

1. What have you tested? Connecting to an application or to the Wildfly-Base-URL([YOUR-IP]:8080)?
2. Are there any other changes in the `standalone.xml`?

FYI: You don't have to use the binding with `0.0.0.0`. It's possible to use `<any-address/>` instead of `<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>`.

Comment: I have tested connecting to my-url:3000/MyApp, there are no other changes in standalone.xml and tried with <any-address> and it doesn`t work

Comment: And how about calling `my-url:3000`. If you see a wildfly starting page then the problem lies within your application

Comment: I solved it. I did the modification in standalone-full.xml and it works. First time I did the modification in standalone.xml and it didn`t work